Cannot change the SQL CommandText within a function nexted in a modules file
I have written a function to log information in different ways and placed that function within a modules file. One option is writing the data to an SQL database.
In my testfile I create an SQL object with a connection string, commandtext, etc. and then call my function WriteLogNew with the SQL object as parameter.
Setting the commandtext property in the SQL Object and then calling the function works fine. But changing the commandtext property within the function results in the following error message:
The property of "CommandText" could not be found for this object
But getting the "CommandText" from within said function also gives the correct result.
I have no idea how to achieve this hence trying to find some help here.
The basic setup is the following (I reduced the files to the absolute necessary information). The modules file looks like this
function WriteLogNew{
    param(
        [string]$output= "",
        [string]$filename = "",
        [string]$path= "",
        [Parameter(Mandatory)][String]$writeLogMethod,
        [MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand[]]$sql
    )

    if($writeLogMethod -eq 'sql'){
        $sql.CommandText = "INSERT INTO `log_test` (`logdate`, `logtext`, `lognumber`) VALUES (NOW(), '" + $output + "', '-2');"
        $sql.ExecuteNonQuery()
    }
}

The testfile looks like this:
$path = $env:USERPROFILE+'\powershell\modules'
Import-Module -Name $path # -Verbose

$argumentsNew = @{
    writelogMethod  = 'file'
}
    
#$SQL_Name=$MysqlhashCred01Plaintext.SqlName
$MariaDB_Server = 127.0.0.1
$MariaDB_User   = 'user'
$MariaDB_Pwd    = 'password'
$MariaDB_Port   = 3306

# Timeout parameters
$timeout    = 3600

# Connect to the libaray MySQL.Data.dll
try{
    Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector NET 9.0\MySql.Data.dll'
}
catch {
}

# Connection LogDB (MariaDB)
$ConnectionString_MariaDB='server=' + $MariaDB_Server + ';port=' + $MariaDB_Port + ';uid=' + $MariaDB_User + ' ;pwd=' + $MariaDB_Pwd + ';database=ecl;default command timeout=' + $timeout + '; Connection Timeout='+ $timeout
$Connection_MariaDB = [MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection]@{ConnectionString=$ConnectionString_MariaDB}
$Connection_MariaDB.Open()

# Define a MySQL Command Object for a non-query.
$sql_MariaDB = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand
$sql_MariaDB.Connection = $Connection_MariaDB

$output = 'Open the MariaDB connection.'

$sql_MariaDB.CommandText = "INSERT INTO `log_test` (`logdate`, `logtext`, `lognumber`) VALUES (NOW(), '" + $output + "', '-1');"

WriteLogNew @argumentsNew -sql $sql_MariaDB -output $output

# Close the MySQL connection.
$output = 'Close the MariaDB connection.'

$sql_MariaDB.CommandText = "INSERT INTO `log_test` (`logdate`, `logtext`, `lognumber`) VALUES (NOW(), '" + $output + "', '-1');"

WriteLogNew @argumentsNew -sql $sql_MariaDB -output $output

$Connection_MariaDB.Close()

Remove-Module -Name modules


I finally found the error in my method. The parameter "$sql$ in my function "WriteLogNew" was defined as an array. Hence my SQL Object was apparently transformed into an array. Removing the "[]" from the parameter solved the problem.
I.e. the parameters must be defined as
param(
[string]$output= "",
[string]$filename = "",
[string]$path= "",
[Parameter(Mandatory)][String]$writeLogMethod,
[MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand]$sql
)

Please read: Why do we always prefer using parameters in SQL statements?

You've declared the $sql parameter an array of MySqlCommand objects, and arrays don't have a CommandText property - use a loop statement or ForEach-Object to update the command text on each individual command in the array:
if($writeLogMethod -eq 'sql'){
    foreach ($cmd in $sql) {
        $cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO `log_test` (`logdate`, `logtext`, `lognumber`) VALUES (NOW(), '" + $output + "', '-2');"
        $cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    }
}


If you meant to only accept one command object at a time, change the parameter declaration from:
[MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand[]]$sql

to
[MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand]$sql

